# How to rotate an image about a point that is not the image's center point using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rotation

What is the method to use to rotate an image about a point that is not the image's center point using MATLAB?

Comment: The IMTRANSFORM function can be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two rotations of the same angle are equal up to a translation. So you can just do rotation around the center, and then translate the image to put your own center of rotation at its old position.

Comment: "Two rotations of the same angle are equal up to a translation."  Not quite.

Comment: "Two rotations of the same angle are equal up to a translation."  This depends on the center of the rotations and what other transformations are being performed and what order they are performed in.  Two rotations of the same angle x by themselves equals one rotation of 2x - not a translation.  I think you are trying to say the right thing, the way you say it however is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The help to 'rotate' says:

> ROTATE Rotate objects about specified origin and direction.
>       ROTATE(H,[THETA PHI],ALPHA) rotates the objects with handles H
>       through angle ALPHA about an axis described by the 2-element
>       direction vector [THETA PHI] (spherical coordinates).
>       All the angles are in degrees.  The handles in H must be children
>       of the same axes.
>
> ...
>
> ROTATE(...,ORIGIN) uses the point ORIGIN = [x0,y0,y0] as the center
>   of rotation instead of the center of the plot box.

Comment: I think he was rather asking about the function `imrotate`

Answer (score 0):

To rotate about a point other than the origin you:

1. Translate the point you want to rotate around to the origin.  For example, if you want to rotate around (3,5), you would translate by (-3,-5).
2. Perform your rotation.
3. Undo the initial translation.  So in my example you would now translate by (+3,+5).

Comment: The two translations [are equivalent to a single translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56728791/how-can-we-rotate-an-rgb-image-using-nearest-neighbor-interpolation-algorithm-ab/56730080#56730080).