# Rotate image in Matlab about arbitrary points

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to rotate an image in Matlab about an arbitrary set of points.

So far, I have used imrotate, but it looks like imrotate only rotates about the center.

Is there a nice way of doing this without first padding the image and then using imrotate?

Thank you

Comment: [Rotating about an arbitrary point is the same as rotating and then translating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56728791/how-can-we-rotate-an-rgb-image-using-nearest-neighbor-interpolation-algorithm-ab/56730080#56730080). This question is a duplicate of [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026905/how-to-rotate-an-image-about-a-point-that-is-not-the-images-center-point-using) but the answer there is not very good IMO, so I won't close this question.

Comment: [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458442/rotate-a-2d-image-around-specified-origin-in-python) has an answer with code, but it's Python. Maybe you'll be albe to translate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "nice way" is using [imwarp](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html)

Building the transformation matrix is a little tricky.
I figured out how to build it from a the following question: [Matlab image rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40245959/matlab-image-rotation/40248435#40248435)
The transformation supports rotation, translation and zoom.

Parameters:
(`x0`, `y0`) is the center point that you rotate around it.
`phi` is rotation angle.
`sx`, `sy` are horizontal and vertical zoom (set to value to `1`).
`W` and `H` are width and height of input (and output) images.

Building 3x3 transformation matrix:

```
T = [sx*cos(phi), -sx*sin(phi), 0
     sy*sin(phi),  sy*cos(phi), 0
     (W+1)/2-((sx*x0*cos(phi))+(sy*y0*sin(phi))), (H+1)/2+((sx*x0*sin(phi))-(sy*y0*cos(phi))), 1];
```

Using `imwarp`:

```
tform = affine2d(T);
J = imwarp(I, tform, 'OutputView', imref2d([H, W]), 'Interp', 'cubic');
```

---

Here is a complete executable code sample:

```
I = imresize(imread('peppers.png'), 0.5); %I is the input image

[H, W, ~] = size(I);  %Height and Width of I

phi = 120*pi/180; %Rotate 120 degrees

%Zoom coefficients
sx = 1;
sy = 1;

%Center point (the point that the image is rotated around it).
x0 = (W+1)/2 + 50;
y0 = (H+1)/2 + 20;

%Draw white cross at the center of the point of the input image.
I(y0-0.5:y0+0.5, x0-19.5:x0+19.5, :) = 255;
I(y0-19.5:y0+19.5, x0-0.5:x0+0.5, :) = 255;

%Build transformation matrix.
T = [sx*cos(phi), -sx*sin(phi), 0
     sy*sin(phi),  sy*cos(phi), 0
     (W+1)/2-((sx*x0*cos(phi))+(sy*y0*sin(phi))), (H+1)/2+((sx*x0*sin(phi))-(sy*y0*cos(phi))), 1];

tform = affine2d(T);
J = imwarp(I, tform, 'OutputView', imref2d([H, W]), 'Interp', 'cubic');

%Draw black cross at the center of the output image:
J(end/2:end/2+1, end/2-15:end/2+15, :) = 0;
J(end/2-15:end/2+15, end/2:end/2+1, :) = 0;

%Shows that the center of the output image is the point that the image was rotated around it.
figure;imshow(J)
```

Input image:
[image]

Output image:
[image]

---

Note:
Important advantage over other methods (like `imrotate` after padding), is that the center coordinates don't have to be integer values.
You can rotate around (100.4, 80.7) for example.